# How does "axis" attribute work in the below code?

Tags: python, pandas, axis

This code is written in Python.
Pandas dataframe name is 'train' column names in dataframe are 'Age' with the floating values and 'Pclass' with some categorical numbers.

Code:

---

Please find the below code:

```
def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]
    
    if pd.isnull(Age):

        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37

        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29

        else:
            return 24

    else:
        return Age
```

---

```
train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=0)
```

---

Here the 'Age' column is becoming NAN. I didn't understand how the axis column is working and all the records in 'Age' column are becoming NAN.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how axis is working. what I really wanted to ask was how Age column 'values' are converted to 'nan' when I run my function.

Comment: for example : lets take Age = ['23','24','25',nan,'26'] and Pclass = ['1','2','1','3','2']. When I run my above code train['Age'] all the rows are becoming 'nan'. How is it possible when the function impute_age(cols) would be retuning ['23','1'] for above example. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There will be lots of info in google if you looks for pandas axis.

Axis represents the axis you would like to point too, with 0 being the rows and 1 being the columns. So in this example you are using your impute_age function on the rows of the Age and P class columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is bcs your applying the function in column instead of rows.

Example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, 1], [np.NaN, 2], [np.NaN, 1]], columns=["age", "pclass"])
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
     age     pclass
 0   NaN      1
 1   NaN      2
 2   NaN      1
```

**axis = 0**

```
 data[['age','pclass']].apply(print, axis=0)
```

**output**

```
0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: age, dtype: object
0    1
1    2
2    1
Name: pclass, dtype: object

//Iterate through columns
```

**axis = 1**

```
 data[['age','pclass']].apply(print, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
 age       None
pclass       1
Name: 0, dtype: object
age       None
pclass       2
Name: 1, dtype: object
age       None
pclass       1
Name: 2, dtype: object

//Iterate through the row
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination of how axis is working. what i really wanted to ask was how Age column values are converted to 'nan' when i run the above function code.

Comment: for example : lets take Age = ['23','24','25',nan,'26'] and Pclass = ['1','2','1','3','2']. When I run my above code train['Age'] all the rows are becoming 'nan'. How is it possible when the function impute_age(cols) would be retuning ['23','1'] for above example. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The axis attribute means that you apply your function **along** that axis:

```
       column1 column2
      +-------+---------+
row1  |       |         |  ----> axis1
      +-------+---------+
row2  |       |         |
      +-------+---------+
          |
          V
       axis 0
```

If you consider a function like:

```
def sum(cols):
    s = 0
    for i in cols:
        s +=i
    return s
```

and apply it to a dataframe df:

```
total_sum = df.apply(sum, axis = 0)
```

It will take the first column1 and apply the function row-wise following the direction of the arrow (axis 0) in the sketch above.
Next it will take the next column2 and so on. In the end you will have the total sum for each column.

For axis = 1 it will take row1 and apply the function column-wise.
Then it will take row2 and so on.
As a result you will get the sum for each row.

In your example with axis equal 0 it passes the column 'Age' as a series to your impute_age function. Then you access just the two first values (rows) of this series (cols[0] and cols[1]).
The same happens to the next column. That's not what you want.

Instead you want to pass each row to the function and access the columns, therefore you have to specify axis = 1.